# Brasero says that a 700MB CD has not enough free space for 480MB data

Tags: music, cd, burning, brasero

Working with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I have a tracklist composed with Banshee 2.6.2 that consists of 20 tracks for a total of 485 MB. A CD with a capacity of 700 MB is in the tray.  I then send this list to Brasero for burning (via the `write CD` command in Banshee). Brasero 3.10.0 then tells me that the blank CD-R has not enough free space.

I have checked that the file sizes reported by Banshee correspond to those shown by a vanilla `ll -h` command. I have also tried with different CD's. Also, this is not a matter of MiB and MB, since there should be enough space anyway.

Any clues on how to have Brasero use the full capacity of the CD? 
Or, if Brasero is not reliable in that respect, on how to export a playlist from Banshee to a functioning CD-burner?

Comment: Is Brasero converting the tracks to a raw / audio cd format? Or are you just trying to write a data / ISO cd?

Comment: Don't think that Brasero is converting anything, but perhaps yes: I don't seem to have control on that. The tracks are files in flac format and Banshee transfers them into a project for Brasero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just want the files written as a data disk, try using Brasero directly and start a new "Data project", then add the files and you should have a disk (or ISO) about the same size as the files.

It looks like Banshee is *helpfully* telling Brasero to create a "traditional audio CD" and converting the files. I tried having Brasero make an "Audio project" with a single "High-Resolution music file (96 kHz/24 bit FLAC)" (16M file) from Sony's http://helpguide.sony.net/high-res/sample1/v1/en/index.html and it shrunk/converted it to a 6.8M bin/cue image.

Comment: It is possible to drag the Banshee playlist onto a standalone Brasero window opened by the user. Using a data project leads to a medium that is read by the file organizer in the computer, whose tracks can be played by the default media player (Banshee puts them in the 'file system queue' rather than viewing it as a classical CD source). This CD will not be read by a CD player though (those at my disposal are oldish, to be true). So it appears that the choice is between a fat portable, traditional audio CD or a lean less portable data-project CD.